# Android - Call backspace without firing onTextChanged

Tags: java, android, textwatcher

So I am currently working on an application which takes the user input, fires a backspace to delete the input, and then adds some other text. (So yes I am basically overriding their input using a TextWatcher)

No the problem: when I call `text.dispatchKeyEvent(new KeyEvent(KeyEvent.ACTION_DOWN, KeyEvent.KEYCODE_DEL));`, it will fire onTextChanged again and again. Now is there any way to delete the user input without firing the onTextChanged again?

Thanks!

Comment: Have you tried setting the text directly? Something like textView.setText(text.substring(0, length - 1)).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I fixed it by calling `edittext.removeTextChangedListener(this);`, then dispatching the key and then calling `edittext.addTextChangedListener(this);` again. is this a clean way too? happy to hear your opinions.

Answer (score 1):

Don't dispatch key events from inside the onTextChanged callback. You can keep an internal buffer with the text and set the entire TextView to that buffer on every interesting key event.

Answer (score 0):

Probably, you are trying to further change the text the user just changed using a `TextWatcher`. To be able to do that, your best option is to use `afterTextChanged` method:

```
public abstract void afterTextChanged (Editable s)
```

> This method is called to notify you that, somewhere within s, the text has been changed. It is legitimate to make further changes to s from this callback, but be careful not to get yourself into an infinite loop, because any changes you make will cause this method to be called again recursively.

To avoid recursion, you can set a flag indicating you are the one changing the text, and clear the flag in the next call. You can also use the other callbacks (`beforeTextChanged` and `onTextChanged`) to gather more information about the change.

Reference: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/text/TextWatcher.html